# How to create shadow inside TextInput REACT-NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, shadow, textinput

I need to create the same view of TextInput like on photo. Any ideas?
link to photo:
[image: link to photo]

Comment: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/709#issuecomment-295274475 check this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this `inset` property ?

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
```

Comment: i don`t have CSS in React-Native

Comment: @VitenkoVadum maybe you should go for something like this - https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#examples ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `react-native-linear-gradient`. i.e.

```
    <LinearGradient
        style={styles.container}
        locations={[0, 0.15, 0.15]}
        colors={['rgba(200, 200, 218, 0.25)', 'rgba(200, 200, 218, 0.005)', '#eafcff']}
>
        <TextInput
            {/* ... */}
        />
</LinearGradient>

// ....

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        //...
        backgroundColor: '#eafcff',
    },

//...
```